# Delete Characters After A Metacharacter

Tags: r

I have the following column in a dataframe. I've made it a vector below:

```
geneIDsfull=c("TRINITY_DN11579_c0_g1_i1^LAC17_ARATH^Cu-oxidase_3","TRINITY_DN44579_c0_g1_i4", "TRINITY_DN113_c0_g1_i2")
```

What I would like to do is place the Trinity ID number (TRINITY_DN11579_c0_g1_i1) in one column, then place any annotation (LAC17_ARATH^Cu-) in a separate column. Each desired annotation comes after a caret. I tried the following function:

```
sub ("^.*", "", geneIDsfull)
```

but did not have any success. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Just escape the metacharcter `sub("\\^.*", "", geneIDsfull)`.  If you don't escape, the `^` is to spsecify the start of the string and `.*` implies other character.  So, you would be selecting all characters from the start and replace with blank.  Essentiallly, blank will be the output

Comment: I'm still having issues extracting this part of the annotation: ```^LAC17_ARATH^Cu-oxidase_3```, There are several of these that have multiple ^ in the annotation, but for every one I only need to extract what is between the first and second ^ ("LAC17_ARATH").

Comment: In that case, capture as a group `str1 <- "^LAC17_ARATH^Cu-oxidase_3"; sub("\\^([^\\^]+)\\^.*", "\\1", str1)#
[1] "LAC17_ARATH"`